# Foundation 6 nesting default width row inside expanded row

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I want the background of a row full width and the content within it a standard width row.

I'm attempting to do this by created a expanded width row, applying a background to it and nesting a standard row inside it. However the nested row is full expanded width despite not having the expanded class.

Here is my attempt

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-2 large-4 columns"><!-- ... --></div>
  <div class="small-4 large-4 columns"><!-- ... --></div>
  <div class="small-6 large-4 columns"><!-- ... --></div>
</div>

<div class="row expanded">
  Expanded row
  <div class="row">
    <div class="large-12">Nested Row</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/onlyslightly/pen/beqZwo

Is there a way to nest standard width rows inside expanded width rows? Or is there a more appropriate way to perform this action?

Comment: Whoops sorry forgot. It's added now

Comment: In shorts - no. You can simply remove `row expanded` wrapper as have behavior as simple div

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue that was introduced in Foundation 6.2.1:
https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/issues/8886

As you can see in 6.2.0 the inner row works fine: 
http://codeply.com/go/UfbFrTyThU

The issue is still open, but you can workaround it using some extra CSS...

```
.row .row {
    max-width: 75em;
}
```

http://codeply.com/go/vyjVAwXkn4